# for or while loop inside #define directive

Tags: c, for-loop, c-preprocessor

How can I write a `for`/`while` loop inside a `#define` directive in C?

Comment: Do you think that's a good idea? What's wrong with a short function? For instance, a function won't have to leak an iteration variable into the scopes that use it...

Comment: @delnan: While I agree that functions should be preferred to macros in almost all cases, a for loop's declaration (the first part) is required to not be leaked outside.

Comment: @Thomas Edleson: Thinking about it, yes, you're right. Even in older language versions where you can't do `for (int i = 0; ...)`, wrapping it in `do { } while (0)` creates a new scope anyway.

Comment: @delnan: Why not just wrap it in `{...}`; the `do/while` is superfluous.

Comment: @Software Monkey: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-are-there-sometimes-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macr

Comment: @delnan: Ahhh.  Forgot about that particular wrinkle with C - I knew there were good reasons why we require all if/else clauses to use braces - this would be one of them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're probably looking for `\` to continue a macro definition across several lines:

```
#define LOOP(start, end)                  \
  for (int i = (start); i < (end); i++) { \
    printf("%d\n", i);                    \
  }
```

Answer (score 13):

Short answer is "don't".  But if you *have* to, for the love of all that's sacred **don't** do this:

```
#define FOREACH(start, end)                         \
      for (; (start) < (end); (start)++)            \
      {                                             \
        // do something interesting                 \
      }
```

Bad juju all the way around.  Note that `start` *must* correspond to an lvalue; you would not be able to call this as `FOREACH(1,10)`, or `FOREACH((a+b), c)`, or `FOREACH(x++,y++)`.  All of those would lead to a compile-time error (the operand of `++` must be an lvalue, and none of `1`, `a+b`, or `x++` qualify).  Calling it as `FOREACH(x, y++)` will do something you *really* don't want it to do.  Similarly, you wouldn't want to call it as `FOREACH(x, y())`.

You can guard against these problems to an extent by doing something like

```
#define FOREACH(start, end)                        \
do {                                               \
  int i;                                           \
  int j = end;                                     \
  for (i = start; i < j; i++)  {                   \ 
    // do something interesting                    \
  }                                                \
} while (0)
```

Essentially, you're creating local variables corresponding to your macro arguments.  This protects against `start` not being an lvalue, and against `end` having a side effect that gets applied or being a function that gets called every iteration.

But if you're trying to encapsulate a loop that gets called frequently, *put it in its own separate function*.  It's safer and easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: do `lvalue`s exist in C? I thought that was only a C++ thing?

Comment: @Coder:  Yes, lvalues are a thing in C - "An *lvalue* is an expression (with an object type other than `void`) that potentially designates an object;" - C 202x working draft, 6.3.2.1.

Answer (score 5):

Since C doesn't require statements to be on separate lines, you can simply smush together into one long line:

```
#define M while (...) { ...; ...; }
```

Or you could escape newlines in the macro definition:

```
#define M \
  while (...) { \
    ...; \
    ...; \
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
#define something for(;;) printf("hooray, i'm in infinite loop!");


int main() { something }
```

Comment: Doesn't C require a return statement in main?

Comment: That's not relevant to the topic at hand.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: Broken examples aren't relevant?

Comment: I'm not sure if requires, but yes, it is at least a good practice to return something.

Answer (score 2):

```
#define foo(x) do { \
    for(x=0;x<4;x++) x; \
    } while(0) // note lack of trailing ;
```

or in gnu c:

```
#define foo(x) ({ \
    for(x=0;x<4;x++) x; \
    })
```

The latter can be used as a expression, although this one has type void, and thus is not very useful.

Comment: Don't you have a conflict between the macro parameter `x` and the control variable `x` in the for loop?  And why the `do/while(0)`?

Comment: @Software Monkey, the macro parameter `x` is the control variable, I wanted to keep it very simple. The `do`/`while(0)` is to ensure that it isn't accidentally used as eg `foo(i) += 12;` or something else that the compiler would likely happily allow.

Comment: Huh?  So `foo(index)` tries to execute the statement `index` 4 times, using `index` as the control counter variable?

Comment: Pretty much, it's not very useful.

Comment: @Software Monkey: questioner didn't specify what the loop should actually do, presumably that can be filled in later.

Answer (score 2):

This would be a more generic for loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define for_loop(start, end, incr) for(i = start; \
                                        i < end;  \
                                         i += incr)

int main()
{
  int i=0, j=5;

  for_loop(i, j, 1)
    printf("%d\n", i+1);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very concise while still human-readable, and it's extremely versatile (unlike the accepted answer which requires different declarations for different executions). Well done!